# How do I get a ListView to draw over its list items?

Tags: android, listview, customization

I have extended ListView such that I can have a fast scroller.  In the onDraw method I draw a rectangle with lettering along the right edge of the list, and if you are actively sliding your finger up and down I render the current letter in the center of the view.  The problem is the list items render on top.  Not idea.
I am looking for the best way to render my background, then my list items, then my foreground.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override `dispatchDraw()` instead of `onDraw()`, and draw your fast scroller after calling through to the super method.